# Error converting object (string) to Int32: TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype

Tags: python, pandas

I get following error while trying to convert object (string) column in Pandas to `Int32` which is integer type that allows for `NA` values.

```
df.column = df.column.astype('Int32')
```

> TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype

I'm  using pandas version: 0.25.3

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's known bug, as explained [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25472).

Workaround is to convert column first to `float` and than to `Int32`.

Make sure you strip your column from whitespaces before you do conversion:

```
df.column = df.column.str.strip()
```

Than do conversion:

```
df.column = df.column.astype('float')  # first convert to float before int
df.column = df.column.astype('Int32')
```

or simpler:

```
 df.column = df.column.astype('float').astype('Int32') # or Int64
```

Comment: Shocked this bug still exists a year later.

Comment: Unfortunately, this bug still exists as of today, though it sufficiently annoyed me I decided to submit a PR <https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/43949>. Hopefully, that will get through soon, as all tests seem to be passing now.

Comment: The [fix](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/43949) looks slated for 1.4

Comment: This solution gets the next error:
`TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64`
The next solution worked out fine:
`df.column = df.column.apply(lambda x: float(x)).apply(lambda x: int(x))`

Answer (score 3):

As of v0.24, you can use: `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(pd.Int32Dtype())`

Edit: I should have mentioned that this falls under the [Nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/arrays.html#nullable-integer) documentation. The docs specify other nullable integer types as well (i.e. Int64Dtype, Int8Dtype, UInt64Dtype, etc.)

Comment: Worked for me by first converting to float then using this

Comment: This doesn't work. You have to convert to float first then you can convert to pd.Int32Dtype() or pd.Int53Dtype() or "Int32" or "Int64"

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use `df = df.astype({i: type_dict[i] for i in header}, errors='ignore')` to deal with this problem. Note that `attribute errors` is to ignore all kinds of warnings. Though it is very inelegant and possible to cause other critical bugs, it does work in converting `np.NAN` or `` string of int like `100` `` or `int like 100` to pandas.Int.
Hope this could help you.

Comment: Haolin, your proposed method returns NameError: name 'header' is not defined