# Pandas conversion to Int64 with missing values

Tags: pandas, type-conversion, missing-data

Note that I’m using panda 1.1.2 and numpy 1.19.2

### non-working scenario

I have a `provider_frame['NEQ']` series containing `pd.NA` datas among numerical values. The type of the series is `object`.

When reading [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html?highlight=int64#pandas.Int64Dtype) about Int64, I understand that we should use pandas.NA for dealing with missing value. After making sure that my series contains either `pd.NA` or numbers, I’m trying the following :

```py
$ provider_frame['NEQ'] = provider_frame['NEQ'].astype('Int64')

output :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 provider_frame['NEQ'] = provider_frame['NEQ'].astype('Int64')

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5541         else:
   5542             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5543             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,)
   5544             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5545 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    593         self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"
    594     ) -> "BlockManager":
--> 595         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    596 
    597     def convert(

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, **kwargs)
    404                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    405             else:
--> 406                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    407             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    408 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    592             vals1d = values.ravel()
    593             try:
--> 594                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
    595             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    596                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    912     # dispatch on extension dtype if needed
    913     if is_extension_array_dtype(dtype):
--> 914         return dtype.construct_array_type()._from_sequence(arr, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    915 
    916     if not isinstance(dtype, np.dtype):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py in _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype, copy)
    367     @classmethod
    368     def _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype=None, copy: bool = False) -> "IntegerArray":
--> 369         return integer_array(scalars, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    370 
    371     @classmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py in integer_array(values, dtype, copy)
    158     TypeError if incompatible types
    159     """
--> 160     values, mask = coerce_to_array(values, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    161     return IntegerArray(values, mask)
    162 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py in coerce_to_array(values, dtype, mask, copy)
    242             "mixed-integer-float",
    243         ]:
--> 244             raise TypeError(f"{values.dtype} cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype")
    245 
    246     elif is_bool_dtype(values) and is_integer_dtype(dtype):

TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024262/error-converting-object-string-to-int32-typeerror-object-cannot-be-converted) , I understand that due to an issue with pandas, we should convert in two times, first as a float, then as a Int64.

When trying to convert, I have the following traceback :

```py
$ provider_frame['NEQ'] = provider_frame['NEQ'].astype('float')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 provider_frame['NEQ'] = provider_frame['NEQ'].astype('float')

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5541         else:
   5542             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5543             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,)
   5544             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5545 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    593         self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"
    594     ) -> "BlockManager":
--> 595         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    596 
    597     def convert(

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, **kwargs)
    404                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    405             else:
--> 406                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    407             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    408 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    592             vals1d = values.ravel()
    593             try:
--> 594                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
    595             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    596                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    988     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    989         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 990         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    991 
    992     return arr.view(dtype)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NAType'
```

I understand that the type float does not like `pd.NA` type.

### The working scenario

Now, I’ll convert all my  `pd.NA` rows to  `np.nan` with `provider_frame.loc[provider_frame['NEQ'].isna() == True, 'NEQ']=np.NaN`

Then, I’ll do the following code :

```py
provider_frame['NEQ'] = provider_frame['NEQ'].astype('float')
provider_frame['NEQ'] = provider_frame['NEQ'].astype('Int64')
```

`And my conversion will work successfully. If I had tried directly to do`provider_frame['NEQ'] = provider_frame['NEQ'].astype('Int64')` without the float step, the output is :

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 provider_frame['NEQ'] = provider_frame['NEQ'].astype('Int64')

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5541         else:
   5542             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5543             new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,)
   5544             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self, method="astype")
   5545 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    593         self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"
    594     ) -> "BlockManager":
--> 595         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    596 
    597     def convert(

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, **kwargs)
    404                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    405             else:
--> 406                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    407             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    408 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    592             vals1d = values.ravel()
    593             try:
--> 594                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
    595             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    596                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    912     # dispatch on extension dtype if needed
    913     if is_extension_array_dtype(dtype):
--> 914         return dtype.construct_array_type()._from_sequence(arr, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    915 
    916     if not isinstance(dtype, np.dtype):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py in _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype, copy)
    367     @classmethod
    368     def _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype=None, copy: bool = False) -> "IntegerArray":
--> 369         return integer_array(scalars, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    370 
    371     @classmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py in integer_array(values, dtype, copy)
    158     TypeError if incompatible types
    159     """
--> 160     values, mask = coerce_to_array(values, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    161     return IntegerArray(values, mask)
    162 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/integer.py in coerce_to_array(values, dtype, mask, copy)
    242             "mixed-integer-float",
    243         ]:
--> 244             raise TypeError(f"{values.dtype} cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype")
    245 
    246     elif is_bool_dtype(values) and is_integer_dtype(dtype):

TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype
```

### The question

There is obviously something I don’t understand with the conversion process. What would be the best way to convert a series containing `pd.NA` rows to Int64 type ?  Isn’t the purpose of `pd.NA` to allow an easy way to make conversion to Int64 type ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to convert string versions of numbers to Int64:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['10', '20', None, '40']})  # list of strings + None
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'], downcast='float', errors='raise').astype('Int64')

print(df)
      x
0    10
1    20
2  <NA>
3    40
```

You may be able to eliminate the downcast and/or errors parameters in `to_numeric()`, but this version works (pandas ver 1.1.0).